# show that $(-1,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are isometric

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to find a metric $d'$ sucht that $(\mathbb{R}, d')$ and $(X, d)$ with $X = (-1,1)$ and $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ are isometric. I tried the homeomorphisms
$$
 f:\mathbb{R} \to (-1,1) ~ \textrm{ with } ~ x \mapsto \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x-1} 
$$
and
$$
 g:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R} ~ \textrm{ with } ~ x \mapsto \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} x\right)
$$
but i have no idea how to find the metric $d'$?

Comment: Let $\phi\colon \mathbb R \to (-1,1)$ a homeomorphism. Define $d'(x,y) := \left|\phi(x) - \phi(y)\right|$. Then $d$ is as wished and $\phi$ is an isometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you pick your favorite homeomorphism $h:\Bbb R\to (-1,1)$, you can define
$$d'(a,b):=d(h(a),h(b))$$
And this is applicable to your functions by $h:=f$ or $h:=g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a injective $f : \mathbb{R} \to X$, you can use that to *define* a metric $d'$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which makes $f$ isometric. Just set $$
  d'(x,y) = |f(x) - f(y)|
$$